# Get rid of surrounding elements in Backbone.Marionette

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have the following view:

```
return  Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        el: '<section>',

        template: JST['app/scripts/templates/grid.ejs'],
```

that is called like this:

```
// a Layout
regions: {
        grid: '#grid',
        detail: '#detail'
    },

    onShow: function () {

        var detailModel = new DetailModel();

        var g = new GridView(detailModel);

        this.grid.show(g);
    }
```

The question is: How do I get rid of the surrounding section element ? I tried to omit the el property but that gives me the following strange looking div:

```
<div productname>
```

Regards Roger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surrounding element is required for backbone to work. It is essentially a container/placeholder for your view to sit in, whether its contents have been rendered or not.

If you ***really*** insist on not having the container then I would consider resorting to the following:

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md#set-how-views-el-is-attached

```
Marionette.Region.prototype.open = function(view){
  this.$el.empty().append(view.$el.children());
}
```

I say 'resorting' because, in my opinion, this is not how Backbone is supposed to be used and may have side-effects. (im not quite sure what will happen when the view in that region tries to re render; what will it's `el` element be pointing to?)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Scott's answer, it's probably a very bad idea to try and force the removal of the surronding view tags.

All Backbone views are contained within an DOM element. Given this fact, you have 2 main options:

- have Backbone put your view into the default `div` element
- specify which element you want Backbone to wrap your view with, using the `el` or `tagName` attributes

If the "extra" tags are creating issues (e.g. you need to generate a specific HTML set for use with a plugin), then you're not defining the wrapping element properly. For more on the subject, take a look at this blog post of mine: http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/02/03/tutorial-nested-views-using-backbone-marionettes-compositeview/

Edit based on jsFiddle: the reason for your strange behavior is that you were passing a model instance to the `initialize` function. This is then interpreted as attributes for the view and get set as HTML attributes.

The correct way to provide a model instance to a view is :

```
new App.FooterView({
    model: new App.Model()
})
```

In other words, you provide a javascript object to the view, with a `model` property. If you want to learn Marionette basics quickly, check out the free preview to my book: http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf (You'll find how to instantiate a view with a model on pages 15-21)

Comment: One thing that still confuses me is the strange looking div tag, when I omit the el property.

Comment: It does look strange, but you need to put up a jsFiddle reproducing the problem or it'll be impossible to trouble shoot. Most likely, you're passing in some sort of attributes to the view (see http://backbonejs.org/#View-attributes).

Comment: I investigated a bit more. All attributes from my detail model end up as attributes on the div tag. So far I was not able to reproduce this with a jsFiddle.

Comment: The problem is that you can not pass a model as an argument to a view. The following jsFiddle documents the problem ([link]http://jsfiddle.net/M5J8Q/1094/)

Comment: Sure you can: http://jsfiddle.net/M5J8Q/1097/ I've also updated my answer with what your problem was.

Comment: I'm already reading your book  and I think I now understand why Backbone expects a Javascript object.